# Which OJDBC Driver for Java 6?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-6, ojdbc

We're currently using ojdbc14.jar, should we be using ojdbc6.jar ?

**Update: Oracle 10g being used**

Comment: Check this question on "Server Fault": http://serverfault.com/questions/10477/differences-between-classes12-jar-ojdbc14-jar-ojdbc5-jar-and-ojdbc6-jar

Comment: Ok, so even though we're on 10g with should use the latest ojdbc driver - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with java6, you can (and should) use ojdbc6.jar if it is compatible with your database.

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

Comment: We're using 10g release 2 - ojdbc6 is not listed for 10g or am I missing something here?

Comment: @JamesC, either upgrade your oracle version to 11g, or use the ojdbc14 version then. Even if it works (most of the time) it's not officially supported.

Comment: Seems the best advise is to always used the latest driver no matter the DB version according to http://serverfault.com/questions/10477/differences-between-classes12-jar-ojdbc14-jar-ojdbc5-jar-and-ojdbc6-jar

Comment: @JamesC, As I said, it works most of the time, but it's isn't officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes, you should.

Long answer - look at compatibility tables in Oracle JDBC FAQ:

- [Which JDBC drivers support which versions of Oracle Database?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_02)
- [Which JDBC drivers support which versions of Javasoft's JDK?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_03)

For JDK 1.6 and Oracle 10g best option is o