# Migration to JBoss7.2eap from jboss5.1.2eap : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss5.x, jboss-eap-7, dbcp

I have migrated my application from `jboss5.1.2-eap` to `jboss-7.2-eap`and `java6` to `java8` but after migration it is starting giving me exception while starting the server.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource

we have a `datasource.xml` file present in the classpath of the server, having the following line of code.

```
<bean id="beanName" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
```

Also we have `commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar` present in the classpath but it is not working for `jboss-7.2-eap`.

Now I am not sure **if `commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar` is supported by `jboss7-eap`.** as it is present in the classpath of the application(present in the loaded module), but still spring is not able to create the bean for datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that datasource in Jboss EAP  should be placed in standalone.xml configuration file and looks like here:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Altis" pool-name="Altis" enabled="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@255.255.255.255:1521:sid</connection-url>
  <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
  <driver>oracle</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>passwd</password>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

Comment: I have given module and driver info in standalone.xml and Now it started giving me " - failure description: {
  "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
      "jboss.jdbc-driver.com_oracle",
      "jboss.jdbc-driver.com_oracle"
  ],
  "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
      "org.wildfly.data-source.Altis is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_oracle]",
      "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/Altis is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_oracle]",
      "org.wildfly.data-source.Altis is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.com_oracle]"
  ]

Comment: add oracle driver to jboss, for example like here: http://resolvethis.com/jboss-database-driver/

Comment: I have already followed the same but getting this issue. I am not sure if `ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar` is compitable with jdk8. as we were using the same jar for jdk6 earlier with jboss5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922774/which-ojdbc-driver-for-java-6

Comment: I think the issue is with `commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar` compatibility with `jboss 7 eap`, as I have loaded this jar to classpath and also we are using spring for the datasource bean creation . so jndi lookup should not be the solution of it.what you say?

Answer (score 0):

Given module information in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` inside the `WEB-INF` directory of the `war` file.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
  <deployment>  
    <dependencies>  
     <module name="com.oracle.sql" export="true"/>
     <module name="org.apache.commons.dbcp" export="true"/>       
     </dependencies>  
   </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also the module directories should also follow the same naming convention as per the availability of your .class files inside the jar, like in my case I have created module `org.apache.commons.dbcp` as while opening `commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar` file, .class files are present inside `org/apache/commons/dbcp` folder.

**Note:** In case of multiple modules, you need to identify there dependency if a module is dependent on other and that information will be given inside `module.xml` file. like

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.commons.dbcp">  
   <resources>  
       <resource-root path="commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar"/>
   </resources>  
   <dependencies>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.pool"/>
      <module name="com.oracle.jdbc.driver"/>
   </dependencies>
 </module>
```